# Отправка форми Yii2 ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, yii2

Подскажите почему перезагружаєтьса страница?? я же аякс использую???

Моя форма:

```
   <?php $formLeft = ActiveForm::begin(['id'=>'form-left'])?>
            <form role="form" id="form-vol-contact">
                <div class="form-group">

                    <?= $formLeft->field($contact_left, 'name')->textInput(['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'exampleInputName', 'placeholder' => 'Ваше ім\'я'])->label(false)?>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">

                    <?= $formLeft->field($contact_left, 'phone')->textInput(['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'exampleInputPhone', 'placeholder' => 'Ваш телефон'])->label(false)?>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">

                    <?= $formLeft->field($contact_left, 'text')->textarea(['rows' => '5', 'id' => 'exampleInputMessage', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ваше повідомлення'])->label(false)?>

                </div>
                <?= Html::submitButton('Залишити заявку', ['class' => 'btn btn-send', 'id' => 'send-left-form', 'name' => 'contact-button']) ?>

            </form>
            <?php ActiveForm::end()?>
```

мой js:

```
$('#send-left-form').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/site/index',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function(res){
            console.log(res);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Error!');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

И контроллер:

```
    $contact_left = new FormLeft();
    if ($contact_left->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Дякуємо за вашу заявку, ми звяжемся з вами найблищим часом');
        var_dump($contact_left);
    }


    if(\Yii::$app->request->isAjax){
        return 'Запрос принят!';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Оно перезагружается потому что ты не блокируешь отправку формы. Та блокировка что ты написал - блокирует стандартное поведение кнопки submit. 
Тебе необходимо на форму  с `id="form-vol-contact"` повесить обработчик `onsubmit` и писать код в нем.

Answer (score 1):

В Yii2 не используйте перехват `submit` или `click` для отправки форм. Перехватывайте `beforeSubmit` на форме.

`$('#form-left').on('beforeSubmit', function(){ ... });`